# WooCommerce 2.6 breadcrumbs showing incorrectly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

We just recently switched over to WooCommerce 2.6 and now breadcrumbs for single product pages and other WordPress pages are not displaying correctly.  They are showing as a different product than the single product page.  Now it does seem to show correctly for product category pages for some reason.

We have our own child theme of Storefront and we did update Storefront at the same time as WooCommerce but it looks like Storefront is just using the woocommerce_breadcrumbs action to handle the breadcrumbs so I don't suspect Storefront.

We are also using WP Rocket for caching and I have tried turning caching off to see if it was the issue.  It didn't seem to fix the issue.

Any ideas on what is causing the breadcrumbs to display incorrectly on Product and WordPress Pages?

Comment: You would need to contact the theme developer.

Comment: The theme in this case, Storefront, doesn't seem to modify the breadcrumbs but only changes the styling of them.  I believe WooCommerce would be more likely, but since I wasn't the one to purchase the extensions they will not answer support questions from me.  Hence why I am asking here.

Comment: When you activate Twenty16, does it work as expected?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot? And yes, test against Twenty Sixteen... to be sure.

Comment: Yep, you are right it happened to be my child theme of Storefront causing the problems.  They changed how the header is setup and I am not pulling it over to my child correctly.  Thanks for pushing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I had updated the theme and they had changed the header.php template file.  I had to modify my override of that file for it to work again correctly.